# Install NET_DNS2 on Xampp and godaddy

Tags: php, dns, pear

I want to get Domain Name records using PHP. I found this pear package [NET_DNS2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/download) . How can i use this package on Xampp and use libraries. I have  godaddy shared hosting, Can i install this package on my shared server or any other solution to get records.

I can use php native functions `dns_get_record("php.net");` to get DNS information also. if i use them , will it work for every domain ? what are the disadvantages of using native dns records function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to install first the, pear installation wizard,

See the Docs here : http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

Then You can install any pear package using command line

```
pear install package_name
```